# Add rule and validation value from database

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

When user will create a post then i want to check this category belong to type or not. If category belongs to type then store it otherwise give me error

my database table :

```
id  categoryname    type
1   cat1          posttype
2   cat2          posttype
3   cat3          usertype
4   cat4          usertype
```

Now when user create post and send 1 `id` then i will to check it belong to `posttype` or not if it belong to usertype then give me error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what a dd() of your $request looks like:

```
$request = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'categoryname' => 'cat1',
        'type' => 'posttype',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'categoryname' => 'cat2',
        'type' => 'posttype',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'categoryname' => 'cat3',
        'type' => 'usertype',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'categoryname' => 'cat4',
        'type' => 'usertype',
    ],
];
```

Then you can create a [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) rule that looks like this:

```
$rules = [
    ...
    '*.type' => [ 'required', 'in:posttype' ]
    ...
];
```

And then you need to use that rule wither in your form request or in the validator of your controller. If you dont know how to do this, let me know and I will update the answer.

Comment: No, This was my database table, not array of objects

Comment: Please put the request you want to validate in your question.